# Import Module from external cdn into Vue component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, node-modules, cdn

I'm trying to import a module that is only available through a CDN into my Vue 2 app component.

The CDN is available through something like this: https://cdn.myscript.com/myscript.min.js

In my component I would like to use the functionality from a module hosted through that CDN, something like import MyModule from "https://cdn.myscript.com/myscript.min.js". I'm aware that I can't do this, but how can I achieve using the Module in my component methods? I've tried importing as a web-pack external, but wasn't working also.

In my component

```
<script>
import MyModule from "? https://cdn.myscript.com/myscript.min.js ?";

export default {
  methods: {
    switchLang(code) {
      MyModule.switchTo(code);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks for any hint!